# Blazor and gRPC by C# and run at Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, grpc

I am new Blazor and gRPC services and get confused how they can work together after some google.

From what I understand, Blazor has server and client app type, normally Blazor client should connect to the Blazor server(backend service) to do the business logic (such as inserting a record into DB)?

But for gRPC, it contains a gRPC server(backend service already).

In this case, what is the best approach to make them work together?

1. Blazor client -> Blazor Server -> gRPC Server. At this case, the Blazor server is the gRPC client

OR

2. Blazor client -> gRPC server.

Is this a common use case (Blazor and gRPC by C# and run at Linux) in the Blazor and gRPC world? or any site (better with a simple code to demo how this is working) recommend for me to read?

Sorry that my questions are not specific enough as I do not have much idea at the moment.

Additional information on what I want to achieve:

1. It is an application written in C# for both the GUI and Backend and running on Linux
2. It is in a multiple tier architecture, where the GUI (Presentation) contains as less business logic as possible.
3. For the communication between the backend service and GUI, proto is preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blazor is a UI framework for the web. It can be [hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in two ways:

- Server - where all your code is running on the server, all interactions and UI updates are sent over a SignalR  connection.
- Webassembly - all your code is running on the client, inside the web-browser.

There are advantages and disadvantages for each options, as is detailed in the link.

gRPC is a way for computers to talk, and is not directly related to blazor. If you are running blazor on the server you *can* use gRPC to talk to another server, but this would only be needed if you want to split your server into two or more parts. If you are running blazor webassembly you *can* use gRPC to talk to the server, but there are other options like web API or SignalR if you prefer something else.

Comment: It is in multiple tier architecture. Hence, although it may be in the same server, I still need a way for the inter-process communication/gRPC. I would like to select a protocol, which can be used everywhere regardless of the location (same server or not), platform (Windows, Linux, etc.) and language (C#, C++, Java, etc.). It looks to me that gRPC could be a choice.

Comment: @kzfid Sure, if you need a common communication protocol gRPC is a good choice. I cannot speak to how common it is, but the blazor documentation specifically mentions gRPC-web for use with webAssembly, so I would expect it to be fairly well supported.